# create a function and call it within a wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

function.php:

```
<?php

Uxper_Room::check_room_price(get_the_ID(), true);
```

review-order.php:

```
$room_base = isset( $room_base ) ? $room_base : '';
-----------
<span class="accent-color"><?php echo esc_html(Uxper_Room::check_room_price($room_base)); ?></span>
```

what is the correct way to write these expressions, considering that I have little knowledge of php, I would also need to know any things that surround the expression I reported

I'm currently getting an error code

thanks

Comment: If you tell us exactly what the error is, perhaps we can help you to fix it. It's a lot harder if we have to guess....

Comment: Reframe your title as a specific question. You may get a little more traction that way and it is better for the SO Q&A format.

Answer (score 0):

is hard to know how to help you if you don't explain the problem you have.

But in case you got a 500 error, you can edit the wp-config.php file on the root of your wordpress folder, and change the line define `( 'WP_DEBUG', false );` from false to true. And show us the error code.

Cheers and good luck.